# Back to top button won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason the back to top button I am using for this website I coded isn't working at all. When I hide the button it won't reappear so I then made it visible to see if it would work but it still wouldn't do anything. Not sure if it's the rest of the code besides the jquery code that's causing it. I used the back to top btn code elsewhere and it works just fine, also used chrome dev tools and no errors pop up. Any help would be appreciated!

```html
        <html lang="en-US">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Improved Dentistry Site 2</title>
        
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Encode+Sans+Condensed:500" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rajdhani:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <!-- owl carousel -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
        
        <!-- animate css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate-raw.css">
        
        
        <!-- fontawesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3AB7yXWz4OeoZcPbieVW64vVXEwADiYyAEhwilzWsLw+9FgqpyjjStpPnpBO8o8S" crossorigin="anonymous">
       
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dentri-css.css">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dentri-respon.css">
        
        
        
    </head>
    
    
     <body id="dent-body" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".fixed-top" data-offset="65">  
       
        
     <header id="top"><!--************** START OF THE HEADER HERE ************************--> 
       
       
           <div class="info-nav">
             <div class="info-con container">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                      
                       <div class="appt-box">
                          
                           <a href="#"><p><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> | <small>Request Appt</small></p></a>
                           
                       </div><!-- end of appt box -->
                       
                       <div class="dropdown appt-box">
                          
                            <a href="#" class="" type="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><p><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> | <small>Office Hours</small></p></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                              
                                <table class="hours-table table">
    
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col"><small class="bold-small">Day</small></th>
                                        <th scope="col"><small class="bold-small">Hours</small></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row"><small>Mon - Fri</small></th>
                                        <td><small>8 a.m - 6 p.m</small></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row"><small>Sat</small></th>
                                        <td><small>8 a.m - 4 p.m</small></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row"><small>Sun</small></th>
                                        <td><small>8 a.m - 2 p.m</small></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                </table>
                             
                           </div>
                       </div><!-- end of appt box -->
               
                    </div>
                    
                    <div id="wats" class="col-md-6 text-right">
                      <i class="ws-i fab fa-whatsapp-square"> <span class="ws-num"> +1 (914) 646-8467 </span></i>
                    </div>    
                   
               </div><!-- end of row -->
           </div>
       </div><!-- end of info nav div -->
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
        <nav class="nav navbar navbar-expand-lg custom-bar-color fixed-top">
          
          
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://jcdevelops.com/work1/primeDental.html"><img src="img/PRIMELOGO-only-one.png" class="brand-logo"></a>
          
          
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <i class="nav-i fas fa-align-justify"></i>
          </button>
          
    
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse dent-menu" id="navbarSupportedContent">
           
           
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto sti-ul">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class=" nav-link scroll" href="http://jcdevelops.com/work1/primeDental.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link scroll active-a" href="http://jcdevelops.com/work1/about.html" role="button">
                      About
                    </a>
                
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a  class="nav-link scroll" href="http://jcdevelops.com/work1/team.html">Our Team</a>
                </li>
              
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
               <!-- add dropdown-toggle if you want the arrow down when using dropdown menu -->
                <a class="nav-link scroll dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Services
                </a>
                
               <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://jcdevelops.com/work1/cosmeticc.html">Cosmetic</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://jcdevelops.com/work1/preventativee.html">Preventative</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://jcdevelops.com/work1/restorativee.html">Restorative</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Other Services</a>
                </div>
                
              </li>
              
              
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a  class="nav-link scroll" href="http://jcdevelops.com/work1/testimon.html">Testimonials</a>
                </li>
              
              
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link scroll" href="http://jcdevelops.com/work1/contactt.html">Contact</a>
              </li>
              
              
              
            </ul>
            
            
            
          </div><!-- end of collapse menu -->
    </nav>
    
                    
     
     </header><!--************** END OF THE HEADER HERE ************************--> 
        
    
    
    
       
       
    <section id="about-dent"><!--===================== START OF SECTION =====================-->
      
           
               
                       
    
     
    <div class="cont-wrap">
           
               
                
                <div class="about-contains mx-auto">
                    
                    <h2 class="team-h3">About Prime Dental</h2><p class="h-small-p">more about us</p>
                    <div class="content-title-underline">
                       
                    </div><!-- end of content underline -->
                    
                    
                    <br>
                    
                    <img class="" src="img/SU-Design-1524775505.jpg">
                    
                    <p class="h-small-head">Our humble beginnings</p>
                    <p class="">Prime Dental is here to assist you in achieving the best smile possible, with high-end equipment, the latest in training and skilled dental practitioners who love what they do. We are a qualified, friendly team, bringing excellence in dentistry to <a href="" class="about-link">Canterbury</a> and surrounds. But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.</p>
                    
                    <h5 class="h-states">Our Mission</h5>
                     <p>On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. </p>
                     
                     
                     <h5 class="h-states">Our Vision</h5>
                     <p>On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. </p>
    
               <hr class="about-hr">
                
                <div class="cont-contact mx-auto">
                    <h3 class="abu">Top Rated Dentistry Care</h3>
                    <p class="cos">On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain.</p>
                    
                    <a href="http://jcdevelops.com/work1/contactt.html" class="btn btn-cont-contact">Consult</a>
                </div>
         
                </div>
                
               
       
         </div>      
     
            
            
            
            
      
               
             <a href="#top" class="back-to-top"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>    
        
       
        
       
                            
    
            
    
    
    </section><!--===================== END OF SECTION =====================-->   
       
    
    
                      
           </body>
        
        
    
        
    <footer>
    
    
        <div class="footer-bottom text-center">
        
                    <a  href="http://jcdevelops.com/" target=”_blank” class="jcdev-anchor"><small>Developer : </small> <img src="img/JCdev(blackBACK).png" class="jcdev"> 
                    </a>
                    
                    <a href="" class="sitemap">|<p><small> Sitemap</small></p></a>
                    <br>
                    <span class="footer-num"><a href=""><small>Tel: +1 (914) 646-8467</small></a></span>  
                    <br>
                    <p class="footer-p"><span class="copyright-span">Copyright © 2018</span> <b>PRIME DENTAL</b></p>
                    
                    <span class="separate">|</span>
                   
                    <a href="" class="footer-icons"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
                               
                    <a href="" class="footer-icons"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    
               </div>
    
    
    </footer>
        
    
                  
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
                  
    
    <script src="js/dent.js"></script>                         
    <script>
     /*====================================================*/
    /*============== TESTIMONIALS/CLIENTS ================*/
    /*===================================================*/   
    
          
          
          $(document).ready(function(){
                $(window).scroll(function(){
                    if($(window).scrollTop()> 400){
                        $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn('fast');
                    }else{
                        $('a.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                    });
            
                    $('a.back-to-top').click(function(){
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop:0
                    }, 'fast');
                
                    return false;
                });
        
            });
        
    
        
        
     
        
    </script>                                      
                
                        
        
    </html>
```

Comment: I think its working on the snippet

Comment: I have added some text to the `<a href="#top" class="back-to-top"><i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i></a>` part to test it and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think your problem is only caused by the fact that you closed the body tag before the footer tag.
so first try to put the `</body>` right before the `</html>`

Then add to your jquery code a `preventdefault()` fonction before processing

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(window).scrollTop()> 400){
                    $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn('fast');
                }else{
                    $('a.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
                }
                });

                $('a.back-to-top').click(function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop:0
                }, 'fast');

                return false;
            });

        });
```